# List all live IP addresses in network in linux

Tags: linux, grep, ping

I am tasked with using a combination of ping and grep tools on a linux machine to produce a list of ip addresses that are live in the network, I only want to display those that are live. This is my code so far:

```
#!/bin/sh

COUNTER=1

while [ $COUNTER -lt 254 ]
do
  ping 10.1.0.$COUNTER -c 1
  COUNTER=$(( $COUNTER + 1 ))
done
```

Comment: Sounds like your trying to do a school project here -.- Not helping people do their school work :(

You are missing checking if the ping succeeded and storing/outputting the list

Comment: Test the exit status of `ping` so you can display just the live ones.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use nmap:

```
nmap -sP 10.1.0.*
```

gives you all IP in the network.

## Update

If you have to use grep and table:

```
nano liveAddress.sh
```

Fulfill with code:

```
#!/bin/sh

COUNTER=1

while [ $COUNTER -lt 254 ]
do
  ping -c 1 10.1.0.$COUNTER | grep PING | awk '{print $2}'
  COUNTER=$(( $COUNTER + 1 ))
done
```

Save (ctrl+o) and exit (ctrl+x).

```
chmod +x liveAddress.sh
./liveAddress.sh
```

This give you ongly IP of the machine up un network.

Comment: But the OP said he has to use ping and grep.

Comment: There is not question! So I "suggest" to use nmap! (:

Answer (score 1):

Fast response by only using default tools:

```
#!/bin/bash 

IP_PREFIX=$1

if [[ -z $IP_PREFIX ]]; then
        echo "Usage: $(basename $0) 192.168.1"
        exit
fi

export COUNTER=1
while [ $COUNTER -lt 255 ]
do
    TARG="${IP_PREFIX}.${COUNTER}"
    #echo "Pinging $TARG"
    ping $TARG -c 1 -w 4 | grep -B 1 "\b0% packet loss" > /dev/null && \
        echo $TARG is alive. &
    COUNTER=$(( $COUNTER + 1 ))
done

wait
```

Answer (score 0):

First, add a limit of 1 second for ping

```
#!/bin/sh

COUNTER=1

while [ $COUNTER -lt 254 ]
do
  ping -w1 10.1.0.$COUNTER -c 1
  COUNTER=$(( $COUNTER + 1 ))
done
```

name your script s.sh, then

```
. s.sh  | grep '1 received' -B1 | awk {'print $2'}
```

Finally, delete this script and use nmap ; )

Answer (score 0):

Why you need to use `grep`?
Just a bit change to your code can find all alive ips:

```
#!/bin/bash

COUNTER=1

while [ $COUNTER -lt 254 ]
do
  ping -w1 10.1.0.$COUNTER -c 1
  if [ $? -eq 0 ];then
      echo "10.1.0.$COUNTER"
  fi
  COUNTER=$(( $COUNTER + 1 ))
done
```

Answer (score 0):

For users who do not want to install nmap a simple bash script. You can set any C-Class net as parameter.

```
#!/bin/bash
#set -x
net=$1
typeset -i i

for (( i = 1 ;  i<255 ; i++ )) ;
    do
            ip=$net.$i
            ping -c 1 -W1 $ip >/dev/null
            if [ $? == '0' ]
                    then
                    echo $ip exists
            fi
    done
```

Save as **broadcast.sh** and set permissions

```
chmod +755 broadcast.sh
```

Start

```
./broadcast.sh 192.168.200
```

Output

```
192.168.200.1 exists
192.168.200.3 exists
```